# SSL certificate cannot be found on Windows Phone 8 emulator

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm developing program for WP8, that retrieves data from JSON. Connection is secured (url start with https). Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes I start receiving exceptions 
`System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.` 
And this exceptions starts showing for all requests to all https URLs. For http URLs everything goes fine. URL is OK, it is opened in IE on emulator. 
I think, there could be problems with certificate, but why it works sometimes?

```
public static void SendRequest(string requestUrl, Action<Stream, Exception> callback)
{
    var targetUri = new Uri(requestUrl);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
    request.Method = "POST";

    request.BeginGetResponse(ar => ProcessResponse(ar, callback), request);
}

public static void ProcessResponse(IAsyncResult callbackResult, Action<Stream, Exception> callback)
{
    try
    {
        var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        var myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

        callback(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), null);

        myResponse.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        callback(Stream.Null, e);
        Debug.WriteLine("Error in RequestHelper.ProcessResponse\nErrorMessage - " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

**Updated:** The issue is definitely in SSL certificate. I've got a message, when I tried to open web page on WebBrowser control - "We're having trouble with this site's security certificate.". I've clicked "Continue to website", but nothing changed. 
The page still can be opened by IE on emulator.
I've tried to install certificate (Made export from site, and downloaded it with IE. I've got the message, that certificate was successfully added. But I still have error message on WebBrowser control.
Is there any way to install certificate? Or not check for it's validity?

Comment: "Remote server returned NotFound" suggests that it's possibly a problem on HTTP level (unknown resource was requested) rather than indication of certificate-related problem. I suggest dumping the URL you are requesting and analyzing it when the error happens - this would deny or confirm my assumption. SSL-related issues are much harder to track, cause there are plenty of things which can be "not found" on "remote server" (CRLs and OCSP responses, when checked, can be not accessible or missing).

Comment: Added code to the post. Error happens when I'm calling EndGetResponse. The situation is in emulator to my mind, because I do not change url of request. It works fine for some time. And after any build it could be broken. URL of request do not change.

Comment: now,do you know how to check the root CA list in wp ?  I also want to know whether my self-signed certificate installed successfully or not.

Answer (score 1):

Self signed certificate is working fine but you need right Common Name (CN) in your certificate.
CN must be same as your server domain

and than you will need to import cert. to your phone

Comment: can you explain it better? My self-signed certificate is not working

Answer (score 0):

I have met same problem in two applications that are communicated with a sever by `https` and I haven't found how to fix it. But I hacked it. When I get a `WebException: Remote server not found` I will check a `StatusCode` of a `Response` and a `Status` of the web exception and if the `Status` is not `RequestCancelled` (you get such status in fast app switching) I repeat the request. It looks something like this:

```
var httpStatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse) webException.Response).StatusCode;
                if (httpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound || 
                    httpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout ||
                    httpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                {
                    if (webException.Status == WebExceptionStatus.UnknownError && !configuration.IsResending)
                    {
                        configuration.IsResending = true;
                        ResendRequest(configuration, successAction);
                        return;
                    }

                    configuration.IsResending = false;
                    throw new ServerTemporaryUnavailabeException();
            }
```

And the second time execution of the request doesn't return `WebException: Not found`.